# Добавить текст в input jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, javascript

Добрый день, ребята. Получаю список изображений в папке */img/*.

Получаю список по типу:

```
$name = scandir($dir);
for($i=2; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) {
echo '<div class="imgs"><img src="/'.$dir.$name[$i].'" width="60px"></div>';
}
```

Как можно передать имя изображения в инпут:

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" id="ItemIMG" placeholder="Например: http://sitename.ru/img.png;http://sitename.ru/img2.png"></p>
```

**Обновление**

Сделал так:

```
function Add(id) {
        alert('Добавил:' + id);
         };

<div class="imgs" id="Buy" id="IMG" onclick="Add(\''.$dir.$name[$i].'@'.'\');"><img src="/'.$dir.$name[$i].'" width="60px"></div>
```

Но как добавить в input без замены предыдущего?

Comment: Вам нужно передать по клику на изображение?

Comment: Да именно так, нужно добавлять в Input + разделитель, например: по клику добавлялось: img.png@img2.png ....

Comment: Сделал так:
 function Add(id) {
        alert('Добавил:' + id);
         }; 

<div class="imgs" id="Buy" id="IMG" onclick="Add(\''.$dir.$name[$i].'@'.'\');"><img src="/'.$dir.$name[$i].'" width="60px"></div>

Но как добавить в input, без замены предыдущего?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".imgs").click(function(){
    if ($("#ItemIMG").val()==''){
        $("#ItemIMG").val($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    } else {
        $("#ItemIMG").val($("#ItemIMG").val()+'@'+$(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Так получаю: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: onclick